# How is the Google SEO performance of REST API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, url-rewriting

I have a web site that developped by `Asp.Net` `MVC4` with using REST API. Our URLs are something like `"/categories/{categoryname}/games/{gamename}"` well designed with REST API. So my question is,

How about the using REST API power of Google search index? Is it Google SEO friendly?

Should we change the URLs by using `urlrewrite` modules for better Google indexing? If yes, should we use `urlrewriting` modules, or should we change our routes in `routeconfig`? what is the best practise for `url rewriting` in `asp.net` `mvc`?

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy as it is now is just fine as long as your category names and game names aren't too wordy.

Ex Bad: /categories/first-person-shooter-mild-violence/games/kill-or-be-killed-by-some-company-here.

Ex Good: /categories/first-person-shooter/games/kill-or-be-killed

Your use of which rewriting packages is up to you but the out of the box routing in ASP.NET MVC is just fine based on your example.